# How to make directories writable in Bash Linux (for VS Code)

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio-code

when I try to open Visual Studio Code, it throws an error "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir..."

[Image of VS Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vkh8.png)

How would I go about fixing this?

All help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: run `sudo chown evanheyb9570:evanheyb9570 /home/evanheyb9570 -R`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question